# Parsing plain text database into data structures

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, data-structures, perl-data-structures

I have a 100MB plain text database file which I would like to parse and convert into datastructure for easy access. The environment is perl and cygwin. Since we receive the plain text file with data from third party, I am not able to use any existing parser like xml or google protocol buffers.

Text file looks like below.

```
Class=Instance1
parameterA = <val>
parameterB = <val>
parameterC = <val>
ref = Instance2

Class=Instance2
parameterA = <val>
parameterB = <val>
parameterC = <val>
```

The file contains a huge number class variants.

What would be the best option to parse this ?  Will yacc/lex help me or should i write my own perl parser ?

Comment: What's your expected output?'

Comment: yes you have use YACC/LEX for custom parsing a file and you have build a regec in pearl

Comment: @BhargavModi : _regec in pearl_ ???

Comment: @serenesat shall I post a demo answer but its only an idea purpose ?

Comment: @BhargavModi : Just explain what is _regec_ and _pearl_ ? (_regec in pearl_)

Comment: @serenesat it was my spelling mistake its regex in pearl

Comment: @BhargavModi : pearl ??? If you mean `perl` then again spelling mistake.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: to convert the data to records in perl.

Comment: You should edit your question with an example of your expected output.

Comment: Is the data always separated by a blank line?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. It auto-detects the line ending by checking the first one, and the assumption here is a record is separated by a blank line.

Within each record, key/value pairs are assumed to be joined with an equal sign (`=`), and maybe some whitespace.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my $db_file;

GetOptions(
    'file=s' => \$db_file,
);

sub detect_line_ending {
    my ($fh) = @_;

    my $line = <$fh>;
    # Rewind to the beginning
    seek($fh, 0, 0);

    my ($ending) = $line =~ m/([\f\n\r]+$)/s;

    return $ending;
}

sub process_chunk {
    my ($chunk, $line_ending) = @_;

    my @lines = split(/$line_ending/, $chunk);

    my $section = {};
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        my ($key, $value) = split(/[ \t]*=[ \t]*/, $line, 2);
        $section->{$key} = $value;
    }

    return $section;
}

sub read_db_file {
    my ($file) = @_;

    my $data = [];

    open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
    my $line_ending = detect_line_ending($fh);

    {
        local $/ = $line_ending.$line_ending;

        while (my $chunk = <$fh>) {
            chomp $chunk;

            my $section = process_chunk($chunk, $line_ending);
            push @$data, $section;
        }
    }
    close $fh;

    return $data;
}

print Dumper read_db_file($db_file);
```

Comment: so you are suggesting to write my own parser !

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Modern::Perl;

my %classes;
my $current;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^Class\s*=\s*(\w+)/) {
        $classes{$1} = {};
        $current = $1;
    } elsif (/^(\w+)\s*=\s*(.+)$/) {
        $classes{$current}{$1} = $2;
    }
}
say Dumper\%classes;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Instance2' => {
                         'parameterC' => '<val>',
                         'parameterB' => '<val>',
                         'parameterA' => '<val>'
                       },
          'Instance1' => {
                         'parameterC' => '<val>',
                         'ref' => 'Instance2',
                         'parameterB' => '<val>',
                         'parameterA' => '<val>'
                       }
        };
```